# How do I check if a value already exists in firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my data is structured in Firebase database:

```
qrcode
|- Result
    |--"sit19da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80"
    |-- "sit1901-10-2018asd"
```

In JSON format it's like

```
{
    "Result" : {
        "-LNEU_XD7EqNBJUoGBxL" : "sit19da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709",
        "-LNieDTKW6UaVyd_jRWn" : "sit1901-10-2018asd"
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm making an android app that can scan QR codes and store their data in firebase. I've made it in such a way that codes that don't start with sit19 won't get pushed into the database using the substring method. Now I want to check if the newly scanned code already exists inside firebase. I've tried using .haschild(code) in a for loop but it doesn't exactly work.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            output = result.getContents();

            String TestString = output;

            if(output.substring(0,5).equals("sit19") == false) {
                // display invalid code
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //push to firebase
                DatabaseReference testRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Result");
                //loop through table to see if output is already inside

                testRef.push().setValue(TestString);
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to include a snippet of the actual JSON you're using (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Also show what you tried, because right now the code you shared doesn't even read from the database let alone using `hasChild()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something with the `valueEventListener()` and `dataSnapshot.exists()`. What I am saying is that, you can put appropriate `DatabaseReference` to your child node and then set the `valueEventListener()` to it.

It may look something like this, in code:

```java
final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("qrcode");
                    databaseReference.orderByChild("Result").equalTo(code).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Code exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            else
                                writeNewCode(code);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Here `code` can be the code you are trying to find, in your result node.

Comment: I would like to do the validation inside the else statement which i'm using to push the data into firebase.

Comment: You can add this code inside your `else` statement.

Comment: So I've added it but the only issue is that the Toast method cannot be resolved.

Comment: You don't need to add the `Toast` method instead you can do what you want to do on the condition that the code exists in the `Firebase`, also if you want to get the `Toast`, you can just add it to your app using `import android.widget.Toast;`

Comment: The toast widget is already imported though, but i still get the same error that it can't be resolved. Instead of using a toast to display the error message, what other ways can i use to display the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documents 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

**exists**

**exists() returns boolean**

Returns true if this DataSnapshot contains any data. It is slightly more efficient than using snapshot.val() !== null.

**hasChild**

**hasChild(path) returns boolean**

Returns true if the specified child path has (non-null) data.

```
private DatabaseReference dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference reciverDatabase = dbReference.child(BuildConfig.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).child(currentUser).child(recervier.getId()).getRef();
        dbReference.child(BuildConfig.ARG_CHAT_ROOMS).child(currentUser).child(recervier.getId())
                .getRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                reciverDatabase.child(Constants.MESSAGE).removeValue();
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    // your code


reciverDatabase.child(Constants.CONVERSATION_UNREAD_COUNT).setValue(0);
                    reciverDatabase.child(Constants.CONVERSATION_LAST_MESSAGE).setValue("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```